# Distinct styling of two merged layers lost

Tags: qgis, layers, vector

I merged two shape files of K-12 school districts and intermediate school districts in MI. Basically an ISD contains many K-12 districts within it. There is a field in the attributes table that distinguishes whether the district is a school or an ISD and I've created different symbols for both, however, I can only see one or the other, not both at the same time. What I want is a thick white border around the ISDs and regular black borders for the school districts contained within.

[image: ISD Map]

[image: Both layers selected]

[image: What I want the map to look like]